# JQuery ajax() get xml response text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve some XML from the Gmail API. I have this so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

I know for sure that the array data has a value called `responseText` because the console tells me so when I get my code to log data. However, when I try to log `data.responseText`, it logs data and ignores the fact that I specified a parameter (it doesn't say that responseText is not defined). What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here is a screenshot of what the console says `data` is:

[image]
Edit, in response to Kevin: I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log($("feed fullcount",data).html());
    }
});
```

it says that it "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" :o

Comment: I don't understand "it logs data". What do you mean?

Comment: "it logs data" = `console.log(data)`

Comment: Is it an array or an object, I'm pretty sure dot notation does'nt work very well with arrays ?

Comment: When I try data[responseText], is says that responseText is not defined. I will post a screenshot showing how the console has just told me that it exists.

Comment: The adress seems to return XML (actually it's atom, but that's pretty much the same as XML) when I try it, and that's neither an object nor an array ?

Comment: why is an xhr object being returned as the first parameter in `success`? that doesn't make sense..

Comment: Are you sure there are'nt any other console.logs in your script, as the document is returned correctly, but for some reason a XHR object is logged seperately on it's own line before the document?

Comment: No, he's running it from the console. the first thing logged is the response from $.ajax, the second is his console.log. :) My answer is still correct i think.

Comment: Yup, just tried it in the chrome console, and it does give you the XHR object before the actual result is logged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`data` is not an xhr object, it is your xml string converted into an `XML Document`. Therefore, it doesn't have a `responseText` property unless the xml doc has a responseText node. Also, add `dataType: "xml"` to your ajax options if you are expecting xml.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

<strike>Edit: Now i see in your question (after edit) that it is infact an xhr object... That's odd...</strike>

Comment: So do I treat `data` like an array of the XML nodes now? Because `data.feed.fullcount` returns "Cannot read property 'fullcount' of undefined".

Comment: I'm not sure, is it an XMLDocument or an Object. More than likely it's an xml document and can be traversed similar to html, such as `$("feed fullcount",data)`

Comment: See my edit to the question (as it's hard to post well-indented code in the comments)

Comment: @Bluefire What is the format of the xml document? I can't see it so i'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by format, but here is a screenie of the XML from the console: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9003/54263106.png

Comment: I can see it, and it's regular XML accessed with regular DOM traversing methods in jQuery.

Comment: But how come `console.log($("feed fullcount",data).html());` doesn't work?

Comment: Heh, nevermind, I used the xml2json plugin to get it into JSON. Thanks for your help! Adeneo, I upvoted all your comments so that you do get some reputation for helping.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a text format response to show,
you can simply do `dataType: "text",`

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.xml",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(text) {
    $('textarea').val(text);
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try data.responseText[0] instead of data.responseText.

EDIT: https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/ It asks me to log in.

Comment: When I try to do that, it says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". However, it clearly shows that `data` has a value called responseText when I ask it to tell me what `data` is.